# Hot to get index path for existing object in collection view

Tags: ios, swift3, collectionview, indexpath

I got an array with objects, and populate the collection view with them. For example I have 3 objects inside my collection view. Is there a way, to receive the current index path based on the object name?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

```
let indexPath = objects.index(where: {
    $0.name == "value"
}).flatMap({
    IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0)
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works great.